Approximation by smooth functions - do the derivatives converge locally uniformly?
Say I have a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is continously differentiable and has a bounded derivative. Then I know I can approximate $f$ with smooth functions $\phi_n$ by mollifications such that $\phi_n \to f$ uniformly. My question is then, does the convergence
$$\phi_n' \to f'$$
hold uniformly on compact sets? I know it holds pointwise, but I'm not sure where to begin with a proof/counter example of the uniform convergence.

Is the question whether a specific and yet undisclosed sequence (or class of sequences) of mollifications satisfies $\phi_n'\to f'$ uniformly on compact sets, or is it whether there is a sequence of mollifications such that yada yada yada?

@SassatelliGiulio
Apologies if I wasn't clear. The question is if there exists a sequence of mollifications converging uniformly to $f$ and the derivatives of the mollifications converge uniformly on compact sets to $f'$.

$\phi_n = \eta_n * f$, so $\phi_n' = \eta_n * f'$. You assumed $f'$ is continuous and bounded, so I believe the mollifications of $f'$ do converge uniformly.

@Kakashi Can you perhaps elaborate? Can you always move the differentation of the mollified functions onto $f$? That seems really nice, then I think I can use that $\phi'$ is uniformly continuous on compact sets to get local uniform convergence. Is that what you had in mind?

@Snildt First, I don't think your assumptions on $f$ are enough to ensure the integral $\eta_n * f(x) = \int \eta_n(y)f(x - y),dy$ is well defined. Anyway, you can move the differentiation under the integral, and it will almost always be correct if the resulting integral is well defined. Formally, you would use the dominated convergence theorem to justify it.

@Kakashi Really? Don't mollifiers by definition have compact support, making the integrals well-defined?

Yeah you are right. The integrals are well defined.
